# How can end users create multiple pages in SharePoint 2013 based on a template?

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-template, site

I have a request to create a documentation portal in SharePoint. The portal will be used to document multiple products. 
These are my requirements:

1. Each product will have a page describing it. All the pages will use the same style. The style includes images, text and links.
2. A technical user will create the template.
3. A non-technical end user should be able to create new product pages based on the template and fill the information about the specific product on the page. After that the page should be approved before being published.
4. End users should not be able to modify the layout.

My question is: There is a feature in SharePoint 2013 to accomplish this? I was thinking that maybe I can create a site template for the products and them each product will be a subsite of the products sites.Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you could use the Publishing Infrastructure. With this you build page templates. Normal editors can only use existing template pages.

Answer (score 0):

If it's project oriented documentation you could build an entire subsite with all elements in the site definition. Build one copy of the documents, then duplicate or create this site template for each project request.

Otherwise you might want to look into a more programmatic solution where you gather the content variables and create each page.